# Trigonometric inequality $|\sin{a_1}|+|\sin{a_2}|+...+|\sin{a_n}|+|\cos{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)}| \ge1$ for all real $a_i$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, functional-inequalities

> Prove that for all real numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ the following inequality holds:
>   $$
> |\sin{a_1}|+|\sin{a_2}|+...+|\sin{a_n}|+|\cos{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)}| \ge 1
> $$

Comment: The only thing I tried is the normal mathematical induction, but it doesn't help me

Comment: Too bad, because that was what I was going to suggest. Does the *sum of angles* forumula for $\cos()$ help us at all? Maybe something with that and the *triangle inequality*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\leq|a|+|b|$, $|c+d|\leq|c|+|d|$.

Comment: That helped me to solve it without induction, thank you.

Comment: @SoulEater You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\sin(a_1+a_2)=\sin(a_1)\cos(a_2)+\sin(a_2)\cos(a_1),$$
so
$$
|\sin(a_1+a_2)|\le|\sin(a_1)|+|\sin(a_2)|.$$
Now you can use induction.